# Using Django Managers vs. staticmethod on Model class directly

Tags: python, django

After reading up on Django Managers, I'm still unsure how much benefit I will get by using it. It seems that the best use is to add custom queries (read-only) methods like `XYZ.objects.findBy*()`.  But I can easily do that with static methods off of the `Model` classes themselves.

I prefer the latter always because:

1. code locality in terms of readability and easier maintenance
2. slightly less verbose as I don't need the `objects` property in my calls
3. `Manager` classes have weird rules regarding model inheritance, might as well stay clear of that.

Is there any good reason *not* to use static methods and instead use Manager classes?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Adding custom queries to managers is the Django convention. From the Django docs on [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers):

> Adding extra Manager methods is the preferred way to add "table-level" functionality to your models.

If it's your own private app, the convention word doesn't matter so much - indeed my company's internal codebase has a few classmethods that perhaps belong in a custom manager.

However, if you're writing an app that you're going to share with other Django users, then they'll expect to see `findBy` on a custom manager.

I don't think the inheritance issues you mention are too bad. If you read the [custom managers and model inheritance docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance), I don't think you'll get caught out. The verbosity of writing `.objects` is bearable, just as it is when we do queries using `XYZ.objects.get()` and `XYZ.objects.all()`

Here's a few advantages of using manager methods in my opinion:

1. Consistency of API. Your method `findBy` belongs with `get`, `filter`, `aggregate` and the rest. Want to know what lookups you can do on the `XYZ.objects` manager? It's simple when you can introspect with `dir(XYZ.objects)`.
2. Static methods "clutter" the instance namespace. `XYZ.findBy()` is fine but if you define a static method, you can also do `xyz.findBy()`. Running the `findBy` lookup on a particular instance doesn't really make sense.
3. DRYness. Sometimes you can use the same manager on more than one model.

Having said all that, it's up to you. I'm not aware of a killer reason why you should not use a static method. You're an adult, it's your code, and if you don't want to write `findBy` as a manager method, the sky isn't going to fall in ;)

For further reading, I recommend the blog post [Managers versus class methods](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/feb/25/managers/) by James Bennett, the Django release manager.

Comment: I wonder if someone could elaborate on why a Model Manager is preferred for model initialisation?   I "get it" to have one for extra methods, but just for construction it seems overblown...

Comment: @GreenAsJade for model initialisation, putting the method on the manager is consistent with the existing `XYZ.objects.create()` method. I think my points 2 & 3 above still apply as well. Having said that, you're an adult. If you want to put your initialisation method on the model then go for it if it works for you/your team.