# Django: Custom manager method VS model method to override create?

Tags: django, factory-boy

I'm not sure to understand the actual purpose of using a `create_object()` method in a custom manager, rather than directly in the model, when I need to override the default `Class.objects.create()` method.

The only difference I see is how I would call it:

- `Class.create_object()` if the `create_object()` method is in the model
- `Class.objects.create_object()` if the `create_object` is a custom manager method.

However, I suppose the latter is the right thing to do, based on examples I can see from Django (with `create_user` for example). I just would like to understand why.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320333 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692487/

Comment: Thanks, the accepted answer on that post is very interesting. However,I think it does not directly answer the question for the object creation case. (I actually knew about the benefits of custom querysets).

Comment: I'm not sure what's different about the object creation case. The reasons like following Django convention, code re-usability, not polluting the instance namespace, and so on still apply.

Comment: @Alasdair Oh! I didn't see there was two links in your comment. I just read the second one and understand better now :)